# Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate interface Magento\Framework\App\Config\ConfigSourceInterface when deploying with Capistrano

Tags: magento2, error

In my daily I have installed Capistrano to deploy Magento 2 to a production / staging server.
For this one project whenever I try to run the command `cap staging deploy` it fails every time whenever I try to run any `bin/magento` command with this error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate interface Magento\Framework\App\Config\ConfigSourceInterface in /public_html/releases/20180501160912/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:50
    Stack trace:
    #0 /public_html/releases/20180501160912/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\\Framewo...')
    #1 /public_html/releases/20180501160912/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(144): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Magento\\Framewo...')
    #2 /public_html/releases/20180501160912/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(230): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument(Array, 'Magento\\Framewo...', NULL, 'source', 'Magento\\Store\\A...')
    #3 /h in /public_html/releases/20180501160912/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php on line 50
```

and it fails right after installing magento with `composer update` from a `composer.json` and `composer.lock` file.
The main app work flawlessly but the new deployment in the release folder all fails because of this.
I've tried to cd into the release and clear the `cache` / `generated` folder, but didn't work.
Every `bin/magento` command trigger that error.

Magento 2.2.2
Server OS: Debian GNU/Linux 8.10 (jessie)
No Redis or Varnish Cache
PHP 7.0

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Did you removed some module without uninstall it correctly without the proper way ?

Comment: It's a brand new installation, no modules removed

Comment: Did you happen to solve this? I'm having the same issue now.